# why is this function not returning a renderbox

Tags: android, flutter, rendering, box

I was trying to get the height of the widget  using rendering box But I don't know why the right side function is not returning renderbox. I new to flutter. Plese help me

`final RenderBox box = _activeChallengeKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();`[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.